# Scraping coursera using their API returns not more than 100 courses

Tags: python-3.x, curl, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

This is the curl command I used -->

```
 curl "https://api.coursera.org/api/courses.v1?start=1&limit=11?includes=instructorIds,partnerIds,specializations,s12nlds,v1Details,v2Details&fields=instructorIds,partnerIds,specializations,s12nlds,description"
```

I played around with the query parameters -start and limit, but it just repeats the same 100 courses out of 2150 courses.Here is the link to the course catalog API -->

https://docs.google.com/document/d/15gwppUMLp0s1OhbzFZvFSeTbvFkRfSFIkiIKrEP6cUA/edit

Python code:

```
 import requests
 import json
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 import csv
 import sys
 reload(sys)
 sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')


if __name__ == "__main__":
headers = ({
    "x-user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 
    (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.92 Safari/537.36 
    FKUA/website/41/website/Desktop"})
d = open('result.json', 'r')
data = json.load(d)
print(data)
d.close()

with open("coursera.csv", 'a') as f:

    # Wrote the header once and toggle comment

    header = f.write('instructorIds' + ',' + 'courseType' + ',' + 'name' + ',' + 'partnerIds' + ',' +
                     'slug' + ',' + 'specializations' + ',' + 'course_id' + ',' + 'description' + "\n")


    for i in range(len(data['elements'])):

                instructorIds = data['elements'][i]['instructorIds']

                instructorIds = str(instructorIds)
                if instructorIds:
                    instructorIds = instructorIds.rstrip().replace(',', '')
                    instructorIds = instructorIds.rstrip().replace('\n', '')
                    instructorIds = instructorIds.rstrip().replace('u', '')
                    instructorIds = instructorIds.rstrip().replace('[', '')
                    instructorIds = instructorIds.rstrip().replace(']', '')
                else:
                    instructorIds = ' '
                print(instructorIds)
                courseType = data['elements'][i]['courseType']
                courseType = str(courseType)
                print(courseType)
                name = data['elements'][i]['name']
                name = str(name)
                print(name)
                partnerIds = data['elements'][i]['partnerIds']
                partnerIds = str(partnerIds)
                if partnerIds:
                    partnerIds = partnerIds.rstrip().replace(',', '')
                    partnerIds = partnerIds.rstrip().replace('\n', '')
                    partnerIds = partnerIds.rstrip().replace('u', '')
                    partnerIds = partnerIds.rstrip().replace('[', '')
                    partnerIds = partnerIds.rstrip().replace(']', '')
                else:
                    partnerIds = ' '
                print(partnerIds)
                slug = data['elements'][i]['slug']
                slug = str(slug)
                print(slug)
                specializations = data['elements'][i]['specializations']
                specializations = str(specializations)
                if specializations:
                    specializations = specializations.rstrip().replace(',', '')
                    specializations = specializations.rstrip().replace('\n', '')
                    specializations = specializations.rstrip().replace('u', '')
                    specializations = specializations.rstrip().replace('[', '')
                    specializations = specializations.rstrip().replace(']', '')
                else:
                    specializations = ' '
                print(specializations)
                course_id = data['elements'][i]['id']
                course_id = str(course_id)
                print(course_id)
                description = data['elements'][i]['description']
                description = str(description)
                print(description)




                if description:
                          description = description.rstrip().replace(',', '')
                          description = description.rstrip().replace('\n', '')
                else:
                     description = ' '

                                ####################################################################
                    ### writing the attributes in a csv file


                f.write(instructorIds + ',' + courseType + ',' + name + ',' + partnerIds + ',' + slug + ',' + specializations + ',' + course_id + ',' + description + "\n")
```

Please suggest a way I can scrape all the courses.

Comment: It might help if you add more details about your implementation and the desired output.

Comment: Sure. Thanks. So I am looking to scrape all the courses from Coursera using their API. So I ran a curl command on the API to obtain the JSON, which returns 100 courses by default. Hope that helps. Let me know if you want anything more specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get all results with a single request if you set the 'limit' to 2150. Example :

```
url = "https://api.coursera.org/api/courses.v1?start=0&limit=2150&includes=instructorIds,partnerIds,specializations,s12nlds,v1Details,v2Details&fields=instructorIds,partnerIds,specializations,s12nlds,description"
data = requests.get(url).json()
print(len(data['elements']))
```

Comment: Thanks, man that helped! I don't why though setting the limit to 2150 in curl command didn't work.

Comment: If you inspect the url in your curl code you'll notice that you have a `?` after the `limit` parameter. If you replace `?` with `&` i imagine curl will work as well.

Answer (score 0):

Can't Scrapy handle sitemap files? There is a [sitemap index](https://www.coursera.org/sitemap.xml) on the coursera site and [one sub sitemap file](https://www.coursera.org/sitemap~www~courses.xml) in particular which lists the pages for all the courses.

If it doesn't, scraping this with StormCrawler should be pretty easy.